# Unable to trigger Cloud Build through Webhook event

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm encountering an issue with triggering a Cloud Build using a Webhook event. Whether I upload the YAML configuration inline or through the CLI, I cannot get the trigger event to start successfully. The triggered build does not appear in the build history.

However, if I deliberately introduce a bug, such as defining a substitution variable that doesn't exist, the trigger will work and the build will fail as expected. Once I remove the bug, the trigger stops working again, even though I receive a 200 response from the endpoint.

For testing purposes, I'm using Postman to trigger the event (using the "Show URL preview" URL). The script I want to run is a simple build script:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'my-image', '.']
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

---

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. So it seems that when the service account which runs the trigger doesn't have enough access rights. No error message, nothing. I was able to resolve it by using the standard cloud build service account (don't specify any specific runner for the trigger).

A resolution from GCP is escribed here: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/troubleshooting#build_trigger_fails_due_to_missing_cloudbuildbuildscreate_permission

However, I cannot confirm that this is enough, because my original trigger (that failed), had these specific access rights and it didn't work.